# Setting up dual monitors (limited access)

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, restrictions

I'm on a school computer, therefore I have no access to the registry and the control panel. I have managed to get CMD open, however. I also have limited abilities when installing software (I can install stuff to my appdata but not to program files).

How can I set up dual monitors (two separate workspaces) utilizing what I have. I could, as a last resort, do this by compiling a short vb.net program (using the already installed .net framework and the provided vbc compiler).

Preferably, I would like to do this through CMD or some kind of .reg script.

I am using Windows XP.

Comment: Operating system? Is it possible that you are not supposed to be doing this, and that is the exact reason they lock it down? Have you tried contacting the school IT team and explaining your reasoning to get them to do it on the up and up?

Comment: I just can't help myself on this one: dueling has been generally outlawed everywhere for at least a century. Walk 50 paces to the corner and think about what you're doing.

Comment: My bad :)  Thanks for the... catch eh?

Comment: This also doesn't answer the question, therefor it is spam.  I have been granted permission to customize my workspace as I want, AS A TEACHER.  currently, however, IT says I am not allowed to have any extra privileges.  According to them, what I am doing now is the most I can do because it has not been blocked.  I'm not getting around anything (it is known by the IT team).  The only reason is because I am not satisfied with two screens with the same image (for obvious reasons).

Comment: Not spam by any means.  As an IT guy myself, if one of my user's decided that they were above the permissions, and tried to work around them, they would be locked down even tighter.  If permissions are put in place, they are there for a reason.  If IT wont change it from Duplicate to extend FOR YOU, that does NOT give you the right to work around their setup.  Talk to your IT people, and tell them this is what you want.  If they CAN do it, they will.

Comment: What is the graphics card brand that you're using?

Comment: @francisswest, I was told it was OK, this isn't your IT team, this is MY schools.  Get over it.  Provide something productive please.

Comment: I am on WINDOWS XP, the card is a... err.. it doesn't say =/

Comment: @DalexL you can look it up in your Device Manager, if you can get to it or if you can run [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/), then that will tell you.

Comment: If you were told that it was OK, then your IT staff should be willing to provide you with a means of accomplishing the task or the support to assist you in setting it up. And if you want people to help you on this site, don't reply to people's comments with snide remarks like "Get over it". If that's the manner in which you interact with people as a teacher, I will hope that no one I know is ever one of your students. This site generally frowns upon people trying to circumvent policies put in place on workplace computers and @francisswest's comments were completely appropriate.

Comment: @bblak I was told that it was OK as long as I was able to do it without extra permission. Their policy states that they can't give extra policies to any teacher or student because that teacher/student could share accounts. francisswests comments were originally posted as "answers" even though they weren't.  He is adding no meaningful content to the question in the form of question or answer, neither are you. I'm not trying to get around anything and have already decided to abandon my quest seeing as too many people believe me to be some sort of trouble maker. THANKS TO THOSE OF YOU WHO DIDN'T!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the MS Virtual Desktop Manager (Power Toys) work in appdata only?

Comment: Sounds like something I might want to look into :)

Answer (score 1):

Using external software that makes the appropriate system calls may be worth investigating. One possible example: http://www.12noon.com/displaychanger.htm

Comment: I'll check it out :)